# OnChange the value input type number call toggle some value work some not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML CODE:

```
<input id="upper" type="number"  min="1" max="9" class="tbox_style" value="1">

 <div class="contents upper">
    <div class="u" id="am" data-color="red" >Upper Material 1</div>
    <div class="u" id="bm" data-color="yellow">Upper Material 2</div>
    <div class="u" id="cm" data-color="blue">Upper Material 3</div>
 </div>
```

JQUERY CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var materials = [];
     $("#upper").change(function() {
            limit = $(this).val();

             $(".u").click(function(){
               var color = $(this).attr('data-color');
               var id = $(this).attr('id');

                $(this).css('background',$(this).attr('data-color'));
                var $el = $(this).toggleClass("u");

             });
       });

 });
```

CSS:

```
.u{
  background:#FFFFFF!important;
  color:#000000;
  }
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kanelit/7e6zncut/2/)

Why my toggle not working with value `1` and  `3`.
Anyone please tell me  how to fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your click function will not work before you have changed the `#upper` once. I suggest that your move the click function out.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var materials = [];
  var limit = $("#upper").val();
  $("#upper").change(function() {
    limit = $(this).val();

  });

  $(".u").click(function() {
    var color = $(this).attr('data-color');
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (limit > $('.upper :not(.u)').length) {
      $(this).css('background', $(this).attr('data-color'));
      var $el = $(this).toggleClass("u");
    } else if (!$(this).hasClass('u')) {
      var $el = $(this).toggleClass("u");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.u {
  background: #FFFFFF!important;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="upper" type="number" min="1" max="9" class="tbox_style" value="1">

<div class="contents upper">
  <div class="u" id="am" data-color="red">Upper Material 1</div>
  <div class="u" id="bm" data-color="yellow">Upper Material 2</div>
  <div class="u" id="cm" data-color="blue">Upper Material 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you , however how you can limited the toggle, example: if I input 2 for upper is mean user can only select 2 colors,?

Comment: thanks a lot, can you help how to change example upper =1 Then I can select another one color.
right now from your code if put `upper=1` then I cannot change to another one color.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Try run the demo now. I believe it's working as your want it.

Comment: I have tested, your code, but seem like problem when we change to 1

Comment: I don't follow you, If i change -> 2 then i can select 2, and if i select it back then i can deselect 1 of the 2 that is already select. Please describe step by step what you do in order to reproduce this problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219744/discussion-between-carsten-lovbo-andersen-and-kn3l).